# Interaction Between Interface Implementation and Private Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

When a class is inherited privately, all members of that class become private in the child class.  However, in the following example, we are able to indirectly access the privately inherited doWork function implementation through AD (pointed to using a pointer to R type).

How is this allowed? Does virtual lookup ignore visibility rules since it is done at runtime?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class R
{
public:
    virtual void doWork() = 0;
};

class RA : public virtual R
{
public:
    void doWork() { cout << "RA doWork\n"; };
};

class P : public virtual R, private RA
{
public:
    P() : RA() {};
};


class AD : public virtual R, private P
{
public:
    AD() : P() {};

    void doWork(int k) { cout << "AD Time dowork " << k << "\n";}
};

int main()
{
    AD ad;
    R* p = &ad;
    p->doWork();
}
```

The above code will print "RA doWork" when run. My expectation was that it would result in a runtime error, because doWork's definition would not be accessible from p due to the private inheritance.

Comment: Access to private variables or classes is resolved at compile-time and is easily defeated. The "private" concept in C++ is not a security feature.

Comment: `doWork` is public through R.  Change to `class AD : private virtual R, private P`, and that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`AD` inherits privately from `P` but publicly from `R`. What this means in practice is that public methods declared in `R` will still be accessible in `AD` but public methods declared in `P` but not in `R` will not be accessible in `AD`. So for example if `P` looked like:

```
class P : public virtual R, private RA
{
public:
    P() : RA() {};
    void doWorkP() { std::cout << "doWorkP" << std::endl; }
};
```

You would be able to access `doWork` through `AD` but not `doWorkP`.

If you want to make `R`'s methods inaccessible in `AD` simply inherit from `R` privately.